Defining not-custom graduated style to polygon layer in PyQGIS
I'm writing some scripts on the PyQGIS 3 console to build a plug-in and I would like to create a color-graduated style for my vector layer. I read Applying graduated renderer to polygon using PyQGIS, but the problem is that the classification method used is custom, I'd like instead that algorithm calculates every percentage, so I must specify only the number of classes and general color, from which to get all shades of the same color. Here is the code of my attempts:
def makeSymbologyForRange(layer, min, max, title, color):
    symbol = QgsSymbol.defaultSymbol(layer.geometryType())
    symbol.setColor(color)
    range = QgsRendererRange(min, max, symbol, title)
    return range

def gradColor(layer, min, max):
    
    campo = 'Cod_DiIoEp'
    myRangeList = []
    myRangeList.append(makeSymbologyForRange(layer, 0, 1.2, '2-4', 
    QColor("Green") ) )   #the problem is that I don't want specify in a customly way every
                           range and color 
    myRangeList.append(makeSymbologyForRange(layer, 1.3, 2.5, '4-6',  
    QColor("Purple") ) )
    myRenderer = QgsGraduatedSymbolRenderer(campo, myRangeList)
    myRenderer.setMode(QgsGraduatedSymbolRenderer.Jenks)
    myRenderer.classificationMethod().classes(min, max, 7)
    
    layer.setRenderer(myRenderer)

The result I got Is a layer with green and purple features corresponding to the values that  I indicated. The code above ignored the rows myRenderer.classificationMethod().classes(min, max, 7).
myRenderer.setMode(QgsGraduatedSymbolRenderer.Jenks)

The layer Indeed Is not divided into 7 classes, but Just into 2. I'd like to find a way to make my layer's style color graduated, without the Need I have to specify for every value range the color and the bounds. For example, I'd like to set a Jenks classification method.

Please [Edit] the Question to state the result of your attempt, and how it doesn't meet your need.

You can use/adapt the following code snippet:
layer = iface.activeLayer()# Polygon vector layer

default_style = QgsStyle().defaultStyle()

# Use any existing color ramp e.g.
# 'Greens', 'Purples', 'Cividis' etc
# or create a custom color ramp
# Here we are using the purple/blue/green
color_ramp = default_style.colorRamp('PuBuGn')

renderer = QgsGraduatedSymbolRenderer()
renderer.setClassAttribute('Cod_DiIoEp')
classification_method = QgsClassificationJenks()
classification_method.setLabelPrecision(1)
classification_method.setLabelTrimTrailingZeroes(True)
renderer.setClassificationMethod(classification_method)
# Calculate specified number of classes based on attribute, method & color ramp
renderer.updateClasses(layer, 7)
renderer.updateColorRamp(color_ramp)

layer.setRenderer(renderer)
layer.triggerRepaint()

# optionally expand the layer legend...
lyr_tree_root = iface.layerTreeView().layerTreeModel().rootGroup()
lyr_node = lyr_tree_root.findLayer(layer.id())
if not lyr_node.isExpanded():
    lyr_node.setExpanded(True)

Example results



It works perfectly !! Thank you very very much

@Salvatore Diolosà, you're welcome. But please don't forget about: https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers. If this answer worked perfectly as you say and solved your problem, it would be appreciated if you marked it as accepted.

I'm sorry. I didn't know it works. Now, I accepted your answer.
